# Jquery and the plug-in Validate, testing for no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I have obviously done something stupid or failed to understand some fundamental process.  Very early days playing with this.

I am trying to check for a form being validated, when the Submit Button is clicked with the onClick method.

`<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="submitForm()" />`

I am using Jquery and the plug-in Validate.  The problem I have is validating on each field is occurring, but if I click on submit with no data or not every field has been tested, I would need to validate the whole form, before submitting, I should get a return of false from `validate().form()`.  This is not occurring as the `else` statement in `submitForm()` is never being executed.

On an empty form, after clicking **submit** the field error messages are shown, but my testing of a return for false, does not seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formEnquiry').validate();
});

function submitForm() {
    $('#msgid').append('<h1>Submitting Form (External Routine)</h1>');
    if ($('#formEnquiry').validate().form()) {
        $("#msgid").append("<h1>(Outside Ready) VALIDATED send to PHP</h1>");
    }
    else {
        $('#msgid').append('<h1>(Outside Ready) NOT VALIDATED</h1>');
    }
};
```

Comment: Think you need to post your validation script and/or your jquery and form. Do you really need a validated message when if it validates shouldnt it be posted and THAT message returned?

Comment: Validated messages, were just for testing the logic was working OK, before next stage of submitting form.  This part seems to be working now, but I can not get the AJAX to work.  I can feel a new question coming on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of Ajax

```
$(function() {
$("#ipenter").submit(function() {
    var ip = $("#ip").val(); 
    var date = $("#date").val(); 
    var spammer = $("#spammer").val(); 
    var country = $("#country").val(); 
    var total = $("#total").val(); 

    var dataString = $('#ipenter').serialize();


        $.ajax({
            url: "/test/process",
            data: dataString,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(msg) {                        
            $('#ipenter').append('<h3 class="gotin">Post succesfull!');
            $('h3.gotin').delay(8000).fadeOut(500);                   
        },
            error: function(data){
            $('#ipenter').prepend('<h3 class="didnt">Post sucked!');
            $('h3.didnt').delay(8000).fadeOut(500);
        }        
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

You dont really even need the val() part

You can also throw some validation into this script before the ajax

```
if (spammer == "") {
        $("#spammer_error").show();
        $("input#image").focus();
  return false;
```

This is a basic example of ajax(I'm using codeigniter so you may need to use a valid URL for the url)